# Modify a custom Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part

i have a custom webpart that need to be modified. The problem is i don't know where to start. The webpart is a Content query webpart that returns a list of news page with title and image.

can you point the steps i need to take to find out how this webpart was created.
Its a bit of reverse engineering here.This webpart was greatly modified by css or html.

Comment: Do you have the solution / project files that you can open in Visual Studio?

Comment: @jpollar I have all the source code but i don't know which code apply to it. Is there a way to find out or i need to read all the files

Comment: If you're only concerned with the display, then you'll want to modify the xsl file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to modify a custom content query webpart.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St

Let me know if this helps or if you have more questions.